# Django test not running specific app tests

Tags: django, testing

I have an app named "sites" that runs normally through the built in server and I can interact with it without any issues.

I added tests in the standard tests.py file and ran "manage.py test sites"

I have two tests in my tests.py file all starting with "test".

When I run the manage.py command in verbose mode, I get:

```
test_get_current_site (django-contrib.sites.tests.SitesFrameworkTests) ... ok
test_save_another (django-contrib.sites.tests.SitesFrameworkTests) ... ok
etc.
```

It looks to me that I have a name conflict with an internal module.
Is there any way I can get manage.py to test my code or should I just bite the bullet and change my app name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your app. From the docs on the [INSTALLED_APPS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#installed-apps):

> **App names must be unique**
>
> The application names (that is, the final dotted part of the path to the module containing `models.py`) defined in `INSTALLED_APPS` must be unique. For example, you can’t include both `django.contrib.auth` and `myproject.auth` in INSTALLED_APPS.

In this case, your `sites` app clashes with [the Django sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/sites/), `django.contrib.sites`.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize that there was something named .sites by default in the settings.  I commented it out temporarily and my tests ran fine. I'll rename my app and be more careful in the future :)